# Azure Load Balancer, IP Source, http session in MVC

Tags: c#, azure, load-balancing

Hi we have been working with the Azure Load Balancer and have the distribution mode set to IP Source. We are of course running multiple web machines.

We are using this with an MVC application. So far we haven't found any issues with maintaining session in Test.

My question is;

Is it normal practice to use IP Source to maintain sticky session's so that the client is always sent to the correct box running In Proc session?

Are there any issues with or pit falls with this setup.

I can't seem to find a definite answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The current best practice is to avoid server-side session state when possible; which ends up being about 95% of the time generally. To do this you would use Cookie-based Authentication in an ASP.NET MVC application. And most data stored within Session state can be cached or loaded on the fly with minimal impact to the system. After all, natively the web is stateless anyway.

IP Source based load balancing is fine; so is using server-side session state if necessary. However, the application really should be designed / built in a fashion that supports it being more stateless. That is that any Session data is just loaded appropriately if it doesn't exist. You really want to gracefully handle user requests without throwing an exception if at all possible so the user can keep getting their job done.

By keeping things more stateless you may get better application performance by using either Round-Robin or Performance based load balancing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, I agree with you on making everything as stateless as possible. As you say though its the last 5% that seems very difficult to get rid of. Long term we won't be using SourceIP through the load balancer. We are looking to move to another shared caching solution. Regis cache has been mentioned. This is a temporary step for us in order to get our application into the cloud.

Comment: Yeah, refactoring out server-side Session state in an existing application can be really tough. Using something like Redis is possible to cache across app instances, but I'd first assess what the performance is to just reload the data every time it's needed. Sometimes the performance hit isn't as bad as you' think, but you'll need to evaluate things fully. Please, don't forget to mark the answer correct if it helps. Thanks!